# How to output PID's into a text file from command line (Windows)

Tags: command-line, pid

I have used various tools that output running processes on Windows, although none of them seem to allow you to export just the pids e.g. one PID on each line for each running process.

Is there a way of doing this from command line?

Answer (score 2):

`tasklist /FO CSV` gives you a csv list, just yank the 2nd column.

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%i in ('tasklist /FO CSV') do (
  echo %%i
)
```

Call this .bat > mytextfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

for xp, vista, windows 7 you can use tasklist at the command promt